How to make studio content changes in Sanity?
I have a Next.js site that is using Sanity. I can npm run dev (localhost:3000), but (localhost:3000/studio) doesn't work. It shows workspace not found. They seems have no connection. If I click go to default workpage, there is no changes on (localhost:3000) when I edit content in default workpage. here
How can I do to fix it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
